# Can not open a browser from an app on Android 10 (API 29) or higher

Tags: android, api, android-studio, android-activity, browser

I created the open_browser function to simply open URLs on a specific built-in browser from my application. The function works perfectly on Android devices that have android API 28 or less.

**Code:**

```
private void open_browser(String website_url, String pkg) {
    String packageName = pkg;
    try {
        browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www." + website_url));
        browserIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        browserIntent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, packageName);
        if(browserIntent != null) {
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "No application can handle this request." + " Please install a webbrowser");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, for Android 10 (API 29) devices or higher, the "startactivity" does not work and I got an error and can not open the browser.

**Error:**
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment StatusFragment{f9df872} (b643f9d3-b322-4e78-bd05-e76970bb6e54) not attached to Activity

The error is pointed to the "startActivity" line.

Can anyone help me to fix this? I want my application works on all Android APIs.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Do without that package name stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There was a change in Android 11. Related to package visibility.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility

Now to use external queries like preview you need to define this type of action in your manifest.

```
<manifest package="com.example.sample">
  ...
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="ndroid:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: I tried this, but still give same error.